# Permanently pin printer indicator to top toolbar?

Tags: printing, indicator

Is there an indicator applet that I can pin to my toolbar which will allow me to view print jobs that are queued for printing?

Comment: Related bug reports: [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/588200) one & [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/771562) - these suggest whitelisting it from being closed or something... **Edit:** Which [might not work](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-get-systray-whitelist-back-in.html) by default in Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is supposed to be an indicator already but it doesn't work.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-printers/+bug/1304434

In the meantime use System Settings → Printers → *printer_name* → View Print Queue.